# ESX + Sysprep.inf + Template= unhappy computername

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, sysprep, powercli

I am trying to create a template in ESX that I can automate with PowerCLI. Everything works great so far, but because I have some specific settings, I had to create my own sysprep.inf.  Now, the computername and the VM guest name are out of synch.  I need to automate this for a sandbox enviornment, so I will constantly be deleting and rebuilding boxes. Thus, I need the VMhost name and the computername to be the same.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you considered using an MDT deployment instead?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure it's still relevant to the OP, it might be relevant to others.
As johnshen64 stated, we can modify the OSCustomizationSpec to set the computer name. We can do it by using the NamingPrefix and the NamingScheme parameters.

e.g.

> New-OSCustomizationSpec -Name **specName** -NamingScheme Fixed -NamingPrefix **hostname**

will create a new specification named **specName** which will set the name of the VM to **hostname**.

---

Reference: [New-OSCustomizationSpec](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FNew-OSCustomizationSpec.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the vm with OSCustomizationSpec to set the computer name to the vm name.